# Getting the output to be correct

Tags: c++, format

In other words, I want it so the numbers line up. However, I can't get my code to do it. Here's my code:

```
 for (int s=0; s < 4; s++)
{
    cout << left << setw(200)  << fuit[s] << ": ";
    for (int x=0; x <13; x++)
        {
        cout << right << setw(2) << fuit[s][x];


}
```

Comment: Why not just `cout <<deck[s][t]<<" ";` ?

Comment: A suggestion: Don't check for `t == 12` for when to print the newline, just do it after the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
cout << left << setw(2)  << suit[s] << ": ";
```

Here you set the alignment to left, and the width to two. You would want it to be right-aligned and with a bigger width.